# How to make a desktop shortcut creator in my .deb package?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, desktop, deb

I was able to build my package, made the control file, everything is fine. It installs the required dependencies if they are not installed, so everything works. The only thing is, if you want to open the installed file you need to go to `/usr/bin` and find the binary and execute it. It works nicely when executed. Is there a way to show it in the list of installed applications after the `.deb` package installs the binaries successfully? It doesn't show up if I do a search. Can a desktop shortcut be made with a post installation file?

Comment: The duplicate is for RPM but the mechanism is identical regardless of how you end up packaging the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `*.desktop` file in folder `~/.local/share/applications/`

For example I have one desktop file for my SoapUI application created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=SoapUI 
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/SoapUI-5.2.1/bin/soapui.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/SoapUI-5.2.1/SoapUI.png
Comment=Web Service Tool
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development
Name[de_DE]=soapui
```

As you can see you can configure there the exec/program to be executed as well as an icon so you can find it when you search for applications in Ubuntu.

Read more, e.g. from https://www.baeldung.com/linux/desktop-entry-files

Comment: I know that part.What I wanted to do is make a shell that creates a desktop shortcut with a postinstall in a deb package.The deb package installs the binaries on /usr/bin/,they can be executed from there.But I would love to make a desktop shortcut when the package installs.I tried this solution but it didn't work https://askubuntu.com/a/52834

Answer (score -1):

After creating a YourApplication.desktop file, add it to the package (as you did the executable) at /usr/share/applications/YourApplication.desktop and an icon as /usr/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/YourApplication.svg (and specify the icon path in the .desktop file)